# How to create HTML table from multiple inputs from user?

Tags: php, html, mysql, postgresql

I have created simple `html` form which has two major inputs:

1. Checkbox for multiple choices (for info: user can select multiple districts)
2. radio button for single input  (for info: user after marking the checkbox in step one will now chose another only one input)
   after this Table should be generated:

**Note:** Multiple tables have same column name so that the displayed table will include the merged data for selected district names

Till now, I have created table for only one district i.e. for individual district. (my database resides in PostgreSQL)

This is **database connection** for my Table:

```
$db = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5433 dbname=MergedDB user=postgres password=admin');
```

I have **two array** for my table:-

```
$userclass = array('0-5','6-10','11-15', '>15','Total');
  $btotal = array();
```

The **query fetching** code is:-

```
$query = " select * from "Arscenic_Test" 
.
.
.
/* some query here*/";

$btresult = pg_query($db, $query);
while($btresults = pg_fetch_row($btresult)){
        $count = count($btresults);
        $y = 0;
        while ($y < $count)
        {
            $c_row = current($btresults);
            $btotal[] = $c_row;
            next($btresults);
            $y = $y + 1;
        }
    }
```

And my **HTML table** is:-

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $userclass[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $btotal[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $perb10[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $bettotal[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pbet[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $b51_100total[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pb51_100[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $bt101_300total[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pb101_300[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $abov300total[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pabov300[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total[$i];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ptotal[$i];?></td>
</tr>
```

How to give User a multiple choices and generate the table as per his inputs?

Comment: Everyone's question is urgent. Yours is not any different

Answer (score 1):

First of all fetch all the districts from the database and render it to the html table. Then you can choose different district from drop-down menu.

Sample Code:

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","nalin","nalin123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT district FROM District");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>District</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['district'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Nalin. but do you think this extract the District Dynamically? if so then how? moreover i need another parameter (that i have already mentioned above) that should work collaboratively with District. how to do that?

Comment: Suppose that you have District Table in your database; and there is a field name district which contains name of different districts; (Let it be, **Kathmandu**, **Chitwan**, **Butwal**) then, when you loop the result in while loop, you will get different districts in the html table.

Comment: i mentioned you before that i have different districts in different table (or relation)  but in same DB but not in same table. the query should render different tables during the inputs being provided by the user. how to do that?

Comment: In that case, you should fetch those district value from each relation and push that value in **List data type**. You can check for data duplication in that List too. Then you can render that List to the HTML table.

Comment: how to push the values in list data type? can you please suggest any links or any ideas?

Comment: You can use **array_push()** function to push the data item into an array.
You can define array list as **$a=array("Chitwan","Kathmandu");**
And if you have to push **Butwal** inside the array **$a**, then use **array_push()** function as **array_push($a,"Butwal");**